# How to solve the redirection problem for bots?

Tags: javascript, redirect, next.js, middleware, next.js14

While trying to index my site in Google search console or another seo checker platform,

I get the warning Page cannot be indexed: Redirect error. The reason for this is the language middleware in project. Here, the end of the url must be /de or /en, otherwise a 404 error "not found" is received. because the folder structure is set to app/[lng]/page.jsx. Normally, there is no problem when accessing from a phone or laptop. But this redirect error occurs in SEO tools or tools such as Google URL Inspection.

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { fallbackLng, languages } from "@/app/i18n/settings";

const cookieName = "i18next";

const languageMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    const cookieLng = req.cookies.get(cookieName)?.value;
    const pathLang = req.nextUrl.pathname.split("/")[1].toLowerCase().trim();
    const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

    if (req.nextUrl.pathname === "/") {
        const browserLang = req.headers.get("accept-language")?.split(",")[0].split("-")[0];

        if (languages.includes(browserLang)) {
            return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${browserLang}`, req.url));
        }

        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${fallbackLng}`, req.url));
    }

    if (!languages.includes(pathLang)) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${fallbackLng}`, req.url));
    }

    if (cookieLng && pathLang !== cookieLng) {
        const response = NextResponse.redirect(req.url);

        response.cookies.set(cookieName, pathLang, {
            sameSite: 'Lax',
            secure: !isDevelopment,
            path: '/'
        });

        return response;
    }

    if (!cookieLng) {
        const response = NextResponse.redirect(req.url);

        response.cookies.set(cookieName, pathLang, {
            sameSite: 'Lax',
            secure: !isDevelopment,
            path: '/',
        });

        return response;
    }

    return next();
}

export default languageMiddleware;
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does it occur with tools like https://curl.se?

Comment: It is not accessed by Google search console or SEO control tools. 307 http code is coming and it goes into a continuous refresh cycle. But normally everyone can access it.

Comment: Are you refreshing unless a cookie is set?

Comment: Yes, the problem was in cookie setting. This obligation created problems for those systems. Now I solved the problem. Thanks